# Can I connect a USB 3 hub to a USB-C port on my computer?

Tags: usb-3, usb-c, usb-hub

I have a nice USB 3 hub ([Anker USB 3.0 SuperSpeed 10-Port Hub](https://www.anker.com/products/o7510)) that has a bunch of USB 3 ports, and USB 3 cable to connect to computer. The hub also has external power. However, my computer, a brand new MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021), has only USB C ports.

I thought I can continue to use my hub my getting a USB 3 female to USB C male adapter, and just connecting the hub to USB C that way.

When I make the connection this way, and try to plug some devices into my hub, nothing happens. The LED on the hub port does not light up, and the device thinks there is no connection.

Is it fundamentally impossible to connect USB 3 hubs to USB C ports this way, or is this a matter of port or adapter incompatibility?

Comment: Certainly not impossible because there are many USB-C docking stations with USB3.0 ports.

Comment: “…getting a USB 3 female to USB C male adapter…” What is the exact model of this adapter? Also, looking at the details on the hub, have you tried pulling in the AC power adapter into the hub? You might need to get a USB C to a USB B 3.0 cable like [this one](https://www.cdw.com/product/tripp-lite-3ft-usb-3.1-gen-2-usb-c-to-usb-b-cable-10-gbps-m-m-fast-charging/4302262) to use it with the USB C connector on the MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr

Yes. Just ensure your adapter USB-A *(female)* to USB-C (male) -- or new cable USB-B to USB-C, is designed for both data *and* power.

#### Explanation

Yes, you should be able to add a quality adapter for either the cable or a new cable for the hub and it should work fine. Just be aware many of these adapters or cables are designed only for power (to connect a phone for charging), or only for data.

Branding can be confusing.

Look for something like USB 3.2 gen2 or Thunderbolt 3 (or 4) for fastest speeds which are also more future proof -- but your hub is USB 3.0 with speeds up to 5Gbps.  (Also branded as SuperSpeed USB 3.0 (5 Gbit/s) OR USB 3.1 Gen 1 OR USB 3.2 Gen 1 × 1 -- they all mean the same 5 Gbps, and confusing)